# php code for yes or no

Tags: php

```
<body background="logo1.jpg">
<IMG SRC="ONGC.jpg" ALT="some text" WIDTH=1050 HEIGHT=306>

<form method="post" action="passing.php">
<br>
<font size="5" color="800517"><b>&nbsp;PLEASE LOG IN TO ENTER VISITOR DETAILS</b></font>
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="v1"><b>YES
  <input type="radio" name="yes" value="V2">NO</b></p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="approve"/>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">

</form>
```

i have written this simple program in html..now my query is how do i write down the php code for yes/no button..i.e if yes button is clicked and submitted then only i will be redirected to passing.php page otherwise it will redirect me back to the same current page..thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="1"><b>YES</b>
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="0"><b>NO</b>
```

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['yes'])) {
  // Yes
} else {
  // No
}
```

Using `1`/`0` in combination with [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) in this manner accommodates the user's selection, as well as allowing the value to be completely missing (in which case it defaults to "no").

Yes/no is a boolean (true/false) decision, and it should be treated as such.

Comment: But as @quarry correctly stated above, it could be something other than yes, for instance if some user tries to mess with the page, in which case 'yes' would be assumed. While I like your sollution it depends on the level of security you like to achieve.

Comment: @inVader But if all you are testing is for yes/no, then convention dictates that anything truthy should be treated as yes. That's how PHP works, that's how Javascript works, that's how pretty much everything works. Any user who is messing around with this is trying to break your application anyway, you have asked them a question to which you want an answer - you have to accept any value as *an answer* regardless of what it is. If you want to bork at bad values, just do `if (!isset($var)) { } else if ($var == 'good val 1') { } else if ($var == 'good val 2') { } else { }`

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['yes']
```

Will contain eityer **v1** or **V2** if the user has made choice. Use **isset($_POST['yes'])** to see if a selection has been made or if passing.php has been called without the 'yes' parameter. Then check if it is **v1**, **V2** or something else and handle the cases  accordingly.

Comment: @quarry - Correct, have taken this into account now.

Answer (score 0):

Check which value got set:

```
switch($_POST['yes']) {
  case 'v1': // checked 'yes'
  break;
  case 'V2': // checked 'no'
  break;
  default: // didn't check anything
}
```

You can generate an HTTP redirect with `header('Location: http://example.com/page.php'); exit;`